# ubuntu server on Jetson TK1

Tags: 14.04, server

Can you install Ubuntu server on a [Jetson-tk1](https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1) ([Wiki](http://elinux.org/Jetson_TK1))?
I want to try using it at a low power mini web server.

It comes with Ubuntu 14.04, which locked up after package updates.
I tried restoring the file system with no success.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The documentation indicates the OS is not quite standard Ubuntu 14.40 - http://elinux.org/Tegra/Downstream_SW/Linux4Tegra describes it and the differences. You can certainly run it as a server if you disable or remove the Unity GUI.  What happened, when you restored the original filesystem, then ran "sudo apt-get update" ?

Comment: when I restored it fails to mount the linux file sys, say directory does not exist. I'll try to go back to restore made and see if I can navigate to the on board mmc and check dir